# Objective-C: Working with static variables

Tags: objective-c, struct, message, class-method, ivar

Given the code below, the spaceship (only ever one in the program) checks to see if it can pay for a new part, and 'if (so)', builds it.  When the `payFor:` message is sent, should the iVars be dealt with like below, or should the each transaction be a method like `+(void)deduct: (ShipObject *) cost;`, or should  I use `struct` and use structure arithmetic?

```
@ implementation Spaceship
+(void) payFor: (ShipObject) *shipObject
{
    totalEnergy     -= [shipObject energy];     
    totalCredits    -= [shipObject credits];
    totalSamples    -= [shipObject samples];
}

+(void) buildShipObject: (ShipObject) *shipObject
{
    if ([self canBuild: shipObject]) {
        [self payFor: shipObject];
...
}
```

Thanks for any insights!

Comment: Show us your ivar declarations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, since the methods are class methods, not instance methods, I assume that variables not ivars, but static variables of some sort.

If payments with some, not all, forms of payment are to be allowed (say, only with energy and samples, but not credits) then you should use three different methods. Otherwise, your `payFor` method is very idiomatic to Objective C. Using C `struct` should be reserved for the rare situations where Objective C classes no longer provide adequate performance.

Consider making the spaceship a singleton, and use ivars: this may become handy if you decide to introduce more ships in the game, or do something that's easier done with objects (e.g. externalization of object's state).

Comment: Yes, updated question not instance variable!  I was thinking that in cases where a ShipObject only used 2 forms of payment it would actually use 3, with the one not in use set = 0 (so free).  And yea, I thought to stay away from underlying C as much as possible too (since performance isn't an issue).  Singletons and sharedManagers isn't overkill?

Comment: @user2000809 Given how simple it is to create a singleton in Objective C these days, it is hardly an overkill. In return you get would get the nice things that you get only with objects. For example, if you decide to save the state of your spaceship, you would be able to use `NSCoding`, and do your serialization in a framework-specific way.